# Changing app id of NativeScript app causes app to no longer run on device

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

In my Angular + NativeScript code sharing app, it runs fine on Android if I use the default app id of com.tns.NativeScriptApplication. However, as soon as I change the app id in AndroidManifest.xml, nativescript.config.ts and package.json and add it in app.gradle then it fails to run on my device.

```
Justins-MacBook-Pro-2018:UI justintoth$ tns run android --emulator
...
Gradle build...
         + setting applicationId
         + applying user-defined configuration from /Users/justintoth/Dev/housters/UI/App_Resources/Android/app.gradle
         + using android X library androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0
         + adding nativescript runtime package dependency: nativescript-optimized-with-inspector
         + adding aar plugin dependency: /Users/justintoth/Dev/housters/UI/node_modules/@nativescript/core/platforms/android/widgets-release.aar
         + adding aar plugin dependency: /Users/justintoth/Dev/housters/UI/node_modules/nativescript-ui-listview/platforms/android/TNSListView-release.aar
         + adding aar plugin dependency: /Users/justintoth/Dev/housters/UI/node_modules/nativescript-ui-core/platforms/android/TNSCore-release.aar
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Project successfully built.
The build result is located at: /Users/justintoth/Dev/housters/UI/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
Installing on device 192.168.57.102:5555...
Successfully installed on device with identifier '192.168.57.102:5555'.
Application com.tothsolutions.housters is not running on device 192.168.57.102:5555.
This issue may be caused by:
    * crash at startup (try `tns debug android --debug-brk` to check why it crashes)
    * different application identifier in your package.json and in your gradle files (check your identifier in `package.json` and in all *.gradle files in your App_Resources directory)
    * device is locked
    * manual closing of the application
Unable to apply changes on device: 192.168.57.102:5555. Error is: Application com.tothsolutions.housters is not running.
```

Here are the various configs:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
        android:name="com.tothsolutions.housters"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name="com.tothsolutions.HoustersActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|locale|uiMode"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme">

            <meta-data android:name="SET_THEME_ON_LAUNCH" android:resource="@style/AppTheme" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.tothsolutions.ErrorReportActivity"/>
    </application>
```

app.gradle:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.tothsolutions.housters"
    minSdkVersion 17
    generatedDensities = []
  }
  aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
  }
}
```

nativescript.config.ts:

```
export default {
    id: "com.tothsolutions.housters",
    appResourcesPath: "App_Resources",
    android: {
        v8Flags: "--expose_gc",
        markingMode: "none",
    },
    appPath: "src",
} as NativeScriptConfig;
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "housters",
  "main": "main.tns.js",
  "version": "7.0.0",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "com.tothsolutions.housters"
  },
  ...
}
```

I have tried deleting the packages directory to install a clean build to no avail. Any idea as to what I'm missing? As a side note, the docs seem to be woefully out of date. This is just the latest of many issues I've had getting up and running with Angular + NativeScript, as the docs misled me and I had to resort to github issue tickets and SO threads to straighten me out.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that the AndroidManifest.xml values still need to be set to com.tns.NativeScriptApplication, com.tns.NativeScriptActivity and com.tns.ErrorReportActivity even if you change your app id to something else. After reverting my changes to AndroidManifest.xml then everything started working.

Also of note, I was able to remove the defining of the app id from package.json and app.gradle. Defining it solely in nativescript.config.ts was sufficient to get it working, despite what the docs and cli warnings told me.

Comment: i already applied all changes you mentioned, but I am still getting a similar issue with yours. Can you help me debug this, please? thanks.

Comment: Just make sure, that under the `<application>` tag you're placing the value `com.tns.NativeScriptApplication` and under the `<activity>` tag you are placing the value `com.tns.NativeScriptActivity`. accidentally i just copy pasted the first and place it in both application & activity, then it crashed because it didn't match.